# boost::bind, boost::shared_ptr and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr, boost-bind

I'm new with the Boost library, and I got a problam a bit complex for me.
I tried to reformulate it with an example found in previous question that might fit well my problem.
(The previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057789/boostbind-with-protected-members-context))

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class Base
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Base>,
      private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
        virtual void test() = 0;

protected:
        virtual void foo(int i) = 0;
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
protected:
    void foo(int i)
    { std::cout << "Base: " << i << std::endl; }

    std::map<int, int> data;

public:     

    Derived()
    {
            data[0] = 5;
            data[1] = 6;
            data[2] = 7;
    }        

    void test()
    {
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(),
            boost::bind(&Derived::foo, shared_from_this(),
                boost::bind(&std::map<int, int>::value_type::second, _1)));
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> Base_ptr;

int main(int, const char**)
{

    std::set<Base_ptr> Bases_;
    Base_ptr derived(new Derived());

    Bases_.insert(derived);
    derived->test();


    return 0;
}
```

I have a base object which is contained in a set, and different derived objects (in this example, only one).
The derived object should call his own protected method with a boost::bind.
In the real problem, the boost::bind generate a callback method for an asynchronous operation, it's why (I think) I need a shared_ptr.
Otherwise, using the pointer this instead of shared_from_this() resolve the problem.

When I compile this code, I got a long error message ended with (which I think is the most significant part):

```
bind_test.cpp:43:78:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:156:53: error: pointer to member type ‘void (Derived::)(int)’ incompatible with object type ‘Base’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:156:53: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
```

I tried to manage with more inheritance from enable_shared_from_this, and some static cast :

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class Base
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Base>,
      private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
        virtual void test() = 0;

protected:
        virtual void foo(int i) = 0;
};

class Derived
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>,
      public Base
{
protected:
    void foo(int i)
    { std::cout << "Base: " << i << std::endl; }

    std::map<int, int> data;

public:     

    Derived()
    {
            data[0] = 5;
            data[1] = 6;
            data[2] = 7;
    }        

    void test()
    {
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(),
            boost::bind(&Derived::foo, boost::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>::shared_from_this(),
                boost::bind(&std::map<int, int>::value_type::second, _1)));
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> Base_ptr;

int main(int, const char**)
{

    std::set<Base_ptr> Bases_;
    Base_ptr derived(new Derived());

    Bases_.insert(derived);
    derived->test();


    return 0;
}
```

But I got an error at run-time :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

Might someone have a clue about how to manage that ?
Thanks.

Etienne.

Comment: The `bind` statement makes no sense on multiple counts. Most strikingly, you cannot easily get at the pair's second member like that. Can you rewrite the function signature of `foo()`?

Comment: Inheriting from enable_shared_from_this in base and derived can lead to problems.  I would avoid that route.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657155/how-to-enable-shared-from-this-of-both-parend-and-derived

Comment: @Kerrek SB, in fact, this example is really more simple than the real problem.
Actually I use boost::bind to generate a callback function for asynchronous operation on a socket called socket_ :

    void derived::test()
    {
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
            boost::bind(&Derived::foo, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

foo is my callback, and is actually called handle_read, or handle_write.

Comment: @Tom K, I was confronted to problems due to this double inheritance.
It's why I need to specify :   boost::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>::shared_from_this()  
   
Instead of :   
shared_from_this()

Comment: @Etienne: Be that as it may, that still doesn't save you from having to deal with the map's value being `pair<int,int>`. You either write a little projector function or make the recipient accept the pair...

Comment: @Kerek SB, In my real code, there is no map.  
The map come from the example I used to illustrate my problem.  
If you want to see the actual, and complex problem, give a look [here](https://github.com/gravitezero/Node/blob/experimental/src/input_connection.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with this workaround, but I'm not satisfied with it, so if someone find a better solution, go ahead.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class Base
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Base>,
      private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
        virtual void test() = 0;

//protected:
        virtual void foo(int i) = 0;
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
protected:
    void foo(int i)
    { std::cout << "Base: " << i << std::endl; }

    std::map<int, int> data;

public:     

    Derived()
    {
            data[0] = 5;
            data[1] = 6;
            data[2] = 7;
    }        

    void test()
    {
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(),
            boost::bind(&Base::foo, shared_from_this(),
                boost::bind(&std::map<int, int>::value_type::second, _1)));
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> Base_ptr;

int main(int, const char**)
{

    std::set<Base_ptr> Bases_;
    Base_ptr derived(new Derived());

    Bases_.insert(derived);
    derived->test();


    return 0;
}
```