# std::bind()-ing a base protected member function from a derived class's member function

Tags: c++, c++11, protected, derived-class, stdbind

I want to `bind()` to my base class's version of a function from the derived class. The function is marked protected in the base. When I do so, the code compiles happily in Clang (Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1) but gives an error in both g++ 4.7.2 and in Visual Studio 2010. The error is along the lines of: "'Base::foo' : cannot access protected member."

The implication is that the context for the reference is actually within `bind()`, where of course the function is seen as protected. But shouldn't `bind()` inherit the context of the calling function--in this case, `Derived::foo()`--and therefore see the base method as accessible?

The following program illustrates the issue.

```
struct Base
{
protected: virtual void foo() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual void foo() override
    {
        Base::foo();                        // Legal

        auto fn = std::bind( &Derived::foo, 
            std::placeholders::_1 );        // Legal but unwanted.
        fn( this );

        auto fn2 = std::bind( &Base::foo, 
            std::placeholders::_1 );        // ILLEGAL in G++ 4.7.2 and VS2010.
        fn2( this );
    }
};
```

Why the discrepancy in behavior? Which is correct? What workaround is available for the error-giving compilers?

Comment: Is it intentional that `Derived::foo` calls itself, or is that just a result of simplifying to an example?

Comment: @aschepler That's the "unwanted" part of "legal but unwanted."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer: see [boost::bind with protected members & context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057789/819272) which quotes this part of the Standard

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in clause 11
>   is applied when a non-static data member or nonstatic member function
>   is a protected member of its naming class (11.2)105) As described
>   earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference
>   occurs in a friend or member of some class C. If the access is to form
>   a pointer to member (5.3.1), the nested-name-specifier shall name C or
>   a class derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly
>   implicit) object expression (5.2.5). In this case, the class of the
>   object expression shall be C or a class derived from C.

Workaround: make `foo` a `public` member function

```
#include <functional>

struct Base
{
public: virtual void foo() {}
};
```

Comment: If you can't change `Base`, adapt it with a Derived method (eg,  `void basefoo(){ Base::foo(); }`). Surprisingly and confusingly in Visual C++ (Express 2010), you can actually use `&Derived::Base::foo` to bypass this error but it basically ignores your second argument (ie, it always uses `this`).

Comment: Workaround alternative, use a lambda:
`auto fn = [=](Derived* d) { d->foo(); };  
fn(this);`

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing to do with `bind`.  Because of the piece of the Standard @rhalbersma already quoted, the expression `&Base::foo` is illegal in a non-friended member of `Derived`, in every context.

But if your intent was to do something equivalent to calling `Base::foo();`, you have a bigger issue: pointers to member functions *always* invoke a virtual override.

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl; }
};

class D : public B {
public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "D::f" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.B::f();   // Prints B::f

    void (B::*ptr)() = &B::f;
    (d.*ptr)(); // Prints D::f!
}
```