# Derived class can't access protected member during instantiation

Tags: c++

I want a class to create a `using` alias from the return type of one of its base class' `protected` member functions. However, the following fails:

```
#include <type_traits>
class B
{
protected:
    int fun(){return 0;}
};

class D : protected B
{
    using T = decltype(std::declval<B>().fun());
};

main() {}
```

> ```
> prog.cpp:5:6: error: ‘int B::fun()’ is protected
>   int fun(){return 0;}
> ```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/b5i4Di)

Why doesn't `D` have access to the protected method of its base?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785069/why-cant-a-derived-class-call-protected-member-function-in-this-code