# Cannot use protected operator== in derived class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    int m_foo;
    Foo(int a_foo) : m_foo(a_foo) {}

protected:
    bool operator==(const Foo& a) const {
        std::cout << "Foo: " << m_foo << " == " << a.m_foo << '\n';
        return m_foo == a.m_foo;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    int m_bar;
    Bar(int a_foo, int a_bar) :
        Foo(a_foo),
        m_bar(a_bar)
    {}

    bool operator==(const Bar& a) const {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << m_foo << ", " << m_bar << " == " << a.m_foo << ", " << a.m_bar << '\n';
        return (const Foo&)*this == (const Foo&)a &&
               m_bar             == a.m_bar;
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar a(1, 1);
    Bar b(1, 2);
    Bar c(2, 2);

    std::cout << (a == a) << '\n';
    std::cout << (a == b) << '\n';
    std::cout << (a == c) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In my real code `Foo` is a class which can be instantiated but should not be allowed to use `operator==` and so I made it `protected`. I am getting a compiler error from doing this:

```
foo.cpp: In member function ‘bool Bar::operator==(const Bar&) const’:
foo.cpp:9:7: error: ‘bool Foo::operator==(const Foo&) const’ is protected
  bool operator==(const Foo& a) const {
       ^
foo.cpp:25:43: error: within this context
   return (const Foo&)*this == (const Foo&)a &&
                                           ^
```

Why is this not allowed? Shouldn't the derived class be able to use the `protected` method?

Comment: `return (const Foo&)*this == (const Foo&)a` -- Not sure, but that `==` doesn't seem to be operating on the base class.  It's two independent objects, `*this` and `a`.  The answer given by @MichaelBurr actually makes use of the base class, `Foo::` in the call.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, This kind of makes sense, it is almost as if it were more like the `operator==(const Foo& l, const Foo& r)` signature but I would have thought `(const Foo&)*this` would have produced a `Foo` and then its method would be used

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I thought about this a bit more, and decided that because I did not define a two object equality operator that there should not be a function / method to compare the two objects. Still confused though

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785069/why-cant-a-derived-class-call-protected-member-function-in-this-code has the answer for your question.

Comment: @DineshMaurya, Yes, it makes sense now, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer why (yet), but this alternative syntax does what you want:

```
return Foo::operator==(a) &&  (m_bar == a.m_bar);
```

Comment: I still would like to know the answer but for all practical purposes this works, +1

Comment: I'd have to refresh my memory on the details, but I'm pretty sure this has to do with rules regarding ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup aka Koenig lookup).

Comment: Dinesh Maurya pointed out the why in the comments, going to go ahead and accept your answer because it is the solution to the problem