# Impossible to access protected function in the initialization of the derived class's constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, protected

I'm trying to implement a class `Union` which inherits directly from the class `Shape` (`Union` is a shape composed of multiple shapes).

The (protected) constructor of `Shape` takes a `Point` as input (representing the center of the shape). To construct a `Union` object, the only input is a list of shapes (`const vector<const Shape>`). To implement the constructor of `Union`, I wanted to use an initialization list, as detailed herebelow

```
class Union : Shape
{
public:
     Union(const std::vector<const Shape> shapes): 
     Shape(shapes[0].get_center()), shapes(shapes) {};
     ...
private:
     const std::vector<const Shape> shapes;

}
```

with `get_center()` a protected virtual function of class `Shape`.

```
class Shape
{
protected:
     Shape (const Point& center) : center(center) {};
     virtual const Point& get_center() const =0;
     ...
private:
     const Point center;
}
```

However, when I call `get_center()` in the initialization list of `Union` constructor, there is an error saying that "get_center() is a protected member of `Shape`".

Can someone explain me why I cannot call `get_center()` from the subclass `Union` (which should have inherited the function) ?

Thank you!

P.S.: If I set the function `get_center()` to public, there is no error anymore.

Comment: Do you really mean to use private inheritance?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes. Anyways, when I write `class Union: public Shape {...}`, the problem is still there.

Comment: @Jarod42 But `Union` is a derived class of `Shape`. Shouldn't I have access to `get_center()` function ?

Comment: From a `Union`, yes, not from `Shape`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785069/why-cant-a-derived-class-call-protected-member-function-in-this-code) might help

Comment: Why does `Union` derive from `Shape` when it is, in fact, a collection of `Shape`s?

Comment: @PaulSanders Because different shapes put together form a new shape.

Comment: @gimme_danger Thank you a lot. It is very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue can be reduced to that

```
struct Base
{
protected:
    int i = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    static void foo(Base& b)
    {
        b.i = 42; // Error
    }

    static void bar(Derived& d)
    {
        d.i = 42; // Ok
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a41b89a17eb20bdd)

You can only access protected members through the derived class.