# Why object of derived class d cannot call the protected member function of the class base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-control, protected

Here the object of derived class `d` cannot call the protected member function of the class base.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
protected:
    int i,j;
    void setij(int a,int b)
    {
        i=a;
        j=b;
    }
    void showij()
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
    }
};

class derived : protected base
{
    int k;
public:
    void show()
    {
        base b;
        b.setij(10,20);
        b.showij();
    }

};

int main()
{
    base b;
    derived d;
    d.setij(3,4);
    d.showij();
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output is `10 20`, but the compiler is showing error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You can't call the functions from outside of `derived`, within `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You used `protected` inheritance. The problem is not that the derived cannot access protected methods of the base, but the problem is that you cannot access base methods from outside of `derived`.

If you don't know what protected inheritance means you can read eg here [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

I doubt you wanted to use `protected` inheritance here (why would you?). Change it to `public` inheritance and your code should be fine:

```
class derived : public base ...
```

PS: The error message should have told you what is the actual problem (albeit in a cryptic way). Please next time include it in the question. If you cannot understand it, probably others will.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *lot* wrong with this code. Even if you change the inheritance of class `derived` from `protected` to `public`, the following problems still exist:

1. In class `derived`, statements `b.setij(10,20);` and `b.showij();` will still generate compiler errors. See [Why can't a derived class call protected member function in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785069/why-cant-a-derived-class-call-protected-member-function-in-this-code) for a good explanation. The short explanation: a method can only call a protected method in a base class on the object for which it was originally invoked.
2. Function `main` will not be able to call `d.setij(3,4);` or `d.showij();` because these are protected methods in class `base`.

This should run:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
protected:
    int i,j;
    void setij(int a,int b)
    {
        i=a;
        j=b;
    }
    void showij()
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
    int k;
public:
    void show()
    {
        this->setij(10,20);
        this->showij();
    }

};

int main()
{
    derived d;
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that I have written a wrong cod but thanks for helping I forgot to remove this question but thanks for more satisfying